# How to make android web app?

Tags: android

I'm new to android apps , I want a good tutorial for android web app 
also I have heared aboud webview I think it just include page url and I don't like that I want to have my own app design and display specific data , make filteration , make search and may user whould login too. 
simply another view for my website

Thank You

Comment: Can you explain more what this app is going to do?

Comment: Thank you for your comment , I'm a PHP web developer , I want to make android app for any website I made , I know how to make API in json , and I want to learn the android side .  I hope it is clear :)

Comment: It is still not clear. Please go through this: http://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html  ... learn the basics of android first.... then move on to building apps interacting with websites... You cannot make an app "for any website". I am sure that those websites have different ideas and structure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the kind of web. For example for a blog (Wordpress, Blogger), a social network (facebook, twitter, etc), you can use json objects to interactuate with your web.

I had a simple app that retrieve data from a wordpress blog, you can take a look to learn something about managing json objects and http requests.

This is the link: [Material App, Wordpress Blog](https://github.com/Dahnark/MaterialDesignApp)

Comment: Thank you , I want to make app for any website , I know json part but don't know anything about android developing part , I will take a look on your app , thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code as a reference: [Android XML Multi-Node Reading Using Current Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326601/android-xml-multi-node-reading-using-current-date).
The only difference is that I used XML instead of JSON, but the main concept behind both is pretty much the same. Also I recommend using `Async`.

As for learning Android API, I would go to Youtube tutorials as well as: https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html